# Torsionfree crystalline cohomology implies torsionfree etale cohomology?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology, characteristic-p, crystalline-cohomology

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic $p>0$. Let $W=W(k)$ be the ring of Witt vectors of $k$.

Assume that the crystalline cohomology $H^2_{crys}(X/W)$ is a torsionfree $W$-module.

Question. Does it follow that $H^2_{et}(X,\mathbb Z_\ell)$ is a torsionfree $\mathbb Z_\ell$-module for all prime numbers $\ell$ invertible in $k$?

Do we "expect" the answer to this question to be positive or negative (assuming some standard conjectures)?

Comment: It is certainly not true that $NS(X)$ is torsionfree if it has no nontrivial $p$-torsion.  For instance, Enriques surfaces in characteristic $p\neq 2$ have $2$-torsion in $NS(X)$, yet they have no $p$-torsion, cf. Cossec-Dolgachev.

Comment: @Monsie: Are there specific examples of varieties $X$ you have in mind?   Of course, the question may be reasonable to ask in general, but it's natural to wonder what motivates it.

Comment: Your question is closely related to the first project outline in Bhatt's lecture series for this year's Arizona Winter School, see http://swc.math.arizona.edu/aws/2017/2017BhattOutline.pdf.

Comment: @pbelmans: I think the OPs question is very different, because $p \neq \ell$ (in $p$-adic Hodge theory, one studies the $p$-adic étale cohomology!). Jason's examples would give a negative answer to the question if one can relate the $p$-torsion in $NS$ to the $p$-torsion in $H^2_{\operatorname{crys}}$.

Comment: Ah, in Cossec–Dolgachev **Prop 1.4.4**, they also prove that $H^2_{\operatorname{crys}}$ is torsion free for $p \neq 2$, so @Jason's answer fully settles the question.

Comment: Note however that even for complex varieties, $p$-torsion and $\ell$-torsion have nothing to do with each other if $p \neq \ell$. Much more subtle are questions in integral $p$-adic Hodge theory where one has *different* $p$-adic theories, some of which may have torsions while others do not. This is what @pbelmans was referring to.